# How to configure AutoMapper in Asp.Net 5 Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper in my Asp.NET 5 Core project.

In the Startup file of my project, I added the following

```
Type[] types = all scannable types...

services.AddAutoMapper((serviceProvider, MapperExpression) =>
{
    // Not sure if this is needed
    MapperExpression.ConstructServicesUsing(t => serviceProvider);

    // Manually add the mapping without using a profile for now..
    MapperExpression.CreateMap(typeof(User), typeof(UserViewModel));

}, types);
```

From the above, I am expected to be able to map a `UserViewModel` to `User`. But instead, I am getting the following error

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map
> configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Object -> User System.Object - User

Here is how I am calling AutoMapper from a controller

```
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public UsersController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult<DisplayUserViewModel>> Create([FromBody] UserViewModel viewModel)
    {
        User model = _mapper.Map<User>(viewModel);

        //...
    }
}
```

Here are my models

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I correctly add AutoMapper service to my .Net 5 core project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things are needed:

1. In the `Startup.cs` file:

   ```
   services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
   ```
2. You may create a folder for your mappings and call it `MappingProfiles` or anything you want. And then add your mapping profile classes, note, the class should inherit from `Profile` object of the `AutoMapper` namespace and do the mappings in the constructor.

   ```
    public class UserProfile : Profile
    {
        CreateMap<UserViewModel, User>();
    }
   ```

In your case, it doesn't work because you are doing the wrong mapping direction. You need to make it opposite.

Change to:

```
MapperExpression.CreateMap(typeof(UserViewModel), typeof(User));
```

Comment: Are you able to tell my why my code isn't working? my code is creating the maps without profile

Comment: @Jay I updated my answer. Look at the end.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I had the reverse mapping otherwise my code is correct